# Using a php file as webservice, but also as a normal include file

Tags: php, web-services

We have a `webservice` written in `php`. It's pretty simple, you do a `http request` with a certain "action" (post variable) and the `webservice` executes the function accordingly. This `webservice` is used by our apps (`android` and `iOS`).

We also have a user management system. It started as a create/edit/delete users page, but has since grown a lot to include more features. We would like to use some of the `webservice`'s functionality from within this `php` application.

This is how the `webservice` was designed:

```
include "config.php"; //for database connection
//some more includes for additional classes and functions

$action = $_POST["action"];
switch ($action) {
  case "login": {
    //do login stuff
    break;
  }
  case "get_roster": {
    //do roster list stuff
    break;
  }
}
```

This does not work when including the file from another `php` file however, so I put it in a `function` (so it doesn't execute immediately). To distinguish between a `http` call and an include I added a `$userId` variable. If it is not set the `function` is called immediately, if it is set the function should be called from the file where the `webservice` was included. This works perfectly, but it makes my eye twitch to see this code. I would really like a more elegant solution, but I'm not sure if it's possible. This is how it is coded now:

```
include "config.php"; //for database connection
//some more includes for additional classes and functions

//there is no way to set $userId when doing a http request
//when including this file you can set $userId first so startService() isn't called immediately
if (!isset($userId)) {
  startService();
}

function startService() {
  $action = $_POST["action"];
  switch ($action) {
    case "login": {
      //do login stuff
      break;
    }
    case "get_roster": {
      //do roster list stuff
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this behaviour? What I want is that the `switch case` is executed immediately when doing a `http request`, but not immediately when just including this file from another `php` file.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no simple and solid way to distinguish between them. Are you using REST? As workaround you can define constant at entry point of your system, so you can tell later whether file was included from complex system or requested (similar to your solution, but more specific).

Comment: *Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.) or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.) but SHOULD NOT do both.* - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: @deceze That is a nice idea, but putting the exact same functions in another file is not an option for us. We are still actively developing and functionality might change slightly, maintaining it in two different places is going to make a mess.

Comment: You misunderstood. What I'm saying is that you should not be directly executing your `startService` function in the same file that it is defined in. The solution is pretty simple: define your `startService` as is in one file, but don't call it. Create a second file that `include`s the `startService` definition and calls it. If you just need to `include` your `startService`, you just `include` the file. If you need to execute it, you call the other file that executes it.

Comment: @deceze That's exactly what I was doing right now :). You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it, because that is what I'm going with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty trivial, really: separate the function declaration and the function invocation into two separate files.

*services.php*

```
function startService($action) {
   ...
}
```

*go.php*

```
require_once 'services.php';

startService($_POST['action']);
```

If you keep up this attitude of logical separation between code *declaration* and code *invocation* and additionally *inject arguments* as shown above, you're making your code a whole lot more flexible, reusable and maintainable. What you have here is essentially the humble beginnings of a proper *controller* in MVC terms.